# Cant Get alert() on a Div that loads Google Geo Map

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-visualization

i have a pretty simple code here .

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#chart_div').on('click', function() {
        alert($(this).attr("id"));
    });
</script>
```

and the only think that can be of trouble is that the `chart_div` loads a Google Geo map.

```
 <div id="chart_div" style="width: 1024px; height: 750px;position: relative; overflow: auto;">
 </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

Place you Code in [DOM ready](http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/)

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#chart_div').on('click', function () {
        alert($(this).attr("id"));
    });
});
```

Comment: Great, but why it must be placed in Ready?

Comment: Because it makes sure that when all HTML code is ready then it all call the script inside it.
Your code was called when HTML is not present so no it does not work.

Comment: so either place it in the ready or place it at the end of the file?

Comment: @noobie-php you got it :)